# Cannot connect to NordVPN

Tags: login, vpn

I recently came across a problem with NordVPN.
Today I tried to activate MeshNet on my laptop (Ubuntu 22.04.1), but this error appeared.

```
It's not you, it's us. We're having trouble reaching our servers. If the issue persists, please contact our customer support.
```

I tried to log-out and log-in again, but it kept refusing to login, showing this message when I tried `nordvpn login --token`, and saying that my credentials are wrong with `nordvpn login --legacy` (even though i tried several times making sure the password was correct).

I reinstalled a few times, making sure that the directory in `/var/lib` was deleted and all, but still no luck.

With `journalctl -xb | grep "nord"` this is the [result](https://pastebin.com/EGqeAtgz).
An error caught my eye, which is `default gateway does not exist`, not sure if that's important.

```
Feb 04 16:25:09 allibis-pc systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for nordpass, revision 152...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit snap-nordpass-152.mount has begun execution
░░ A start job for unit snap-nordpass-152.mount has begun execution.
Feb 04 16:25:09 allibis-pc systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for nordpass, revision 153...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit snap-nordpass-153.mount has begun execution
░░ A start job for unit snap-nordpass-153.mount has begun execution.
Feb 04 16:25:09 allibis-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for nordpass, revision 152.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit snap-nordpass-152.mount has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit snap-nordpass-152.mount has finished successfully.
Feb 04 16:25:09 allibis-pc systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for nordpass, revision 153.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit snap-nordpass-153.mount has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit snap-nordpass-153.mount has finished successfully.
Feb 04 16:25:09 allibis-pc audit[751]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.nordpass" pid=751 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 04 16:25:09 allibis-pc audit[758]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.nordpass.nordpass" pid=758 comm="apparmor_parser"
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc systemd[1]: nordvpnd.socket: TCP_NODELAY failed: Operation not supported
░░ Subject: A start job for unit nordvpnd.socket has begun execution
░░ A start job for unit nordvpnd.socket has begun execution.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit nordvpnd.socket has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit nordvpnd.socket has finished successfully.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit nordvpn.service has begun execution
░░ A start job for unit nordvpn.service has begun execution.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit nordvpnd.service has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit nordvpnd.service has finished successfully.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit nordvpn.service has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit nordvpn.service has finished successfully.
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 [Info] Daemon has started
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 Kill Switch set to: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 Firewall set to: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 Routing set to: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 Auto-connect set to: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 DNS set to: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 ThreatProtectionLite set to: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 Protocol set to: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 Meshnet set to: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 IPv6 set to: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 Technology set to: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 Get "https://cdn.zwyr157wwiu6eior.com/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup cdn.zwyr157wwiu6eior.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.otmwumj6qw5em0zb.me/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.otmwumj6qw5em0zb.me: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.judua3rtinpst0s.xyz/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.judua3rtinpst0s.xyz: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.p99nxpivfscyverz.me/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.p99nxpivfscyverz.me: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://cdn.zwyr157wwiu6eior.com/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup cdn.zwyr157wwiu6eior.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.nordcdn.com/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.nordcdn.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.icpsuawn1zy5amys.com/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.icpsuawn1zy5amys.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.mxo4bkqvdityebzvp.xyz/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.mxo4bkqvdityebzvp.xyz: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.wutlk3t9mybdz.info/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.wutlk3t9mybdz.info: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.x9fnzrtl4x8pynsf.com/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.x9fnzrtl4x8pynsf.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.mzhlhrfr8z.info/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.mzhlhrfr8z.info: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.se3v5tjfff3aet.me/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.se3v5tjfff3aet.me: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.njtzzrvg0lwj3bsn.info/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.njtzzrvg0lwj3bsn.info: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.ltlxvxjjmvhn.me/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.ltlxvxjjmvhn.me: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.73dkt-vwrqs.xyz/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.73dkt-vwrqs.xyz: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.tptn0rhbtj.info/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.tptn0rhbtj.info: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.ns8469rfvth42.xyz/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.ns8469rfvth42.xyz: Temporary failure in name resolution
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc nordvpnd[975]: 2023/02/04 16:25:10 default gateway does not exist
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc systemd[1]: nordvpnd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit nordvpnd.service has exited.
Feb 04 16:25:10 allibis-pc systemd[1]: nordvpnd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ The unit nordvpnd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc systemd[1]: nordvpnd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit nordvpnd.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit nordvpnd.service has finished
░░ A stop job for unit nordvpnd.service has finished.
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc systemd[1]: nordvpnd.socket: Deactivated successfully.
░░ The unit nordvpnd.socket has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit nordvpnd.socket has finished
░░ A stop job for unit nordvpnd.socket has finished.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit nordvpnd.socket has begun execution
░░ A stop job for unit nordvpnd.socket has begun execution.
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc systemd[1]: nordvpnd.socket: TCP_NODELAY failed: Operation not supported
░░ Subject: A start job for unit nordvpnd.socket has begun execution
░░ A start job for unit nordvpnd.socket has begun execution.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit nordvpnd.socket has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit nordvpnd.socket has finished successfully.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit nordvpnd.service has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit nordvpnd.service has finished successfully.
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:25:15 [Info] Daemon has started
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:25:15 Kill Switch set to: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:25:15 Firewall set to: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:25:15 Routing set to: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:25:15 Auto-connect set to: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:25:15 DNS set to: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:25:15 ThreatProtectionLite set to: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:25:15 Protocol set to: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:25:15 Meshnet set to: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:25:15 IPv6 set to: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:25:15 Technology set to: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: NordVPN App Connection Settings:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Technology: NORDLYNX
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Meshnet: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Protocol: UDP
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Firewall: enabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: KillSwitch: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Obfuscate: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: ThreatProtectionLite: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: DNS:
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: IPv6: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Notify: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:15 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: Auto-connect: disabled
Feb 04 16:25:16 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:25:16 notifying subscriber: /v1/helpers/ips/insights is not important to moose
Feb 04 16:36:37 allibis-pc sudo[4792]:  allibis : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/allibis ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl enable nordvpnd
Feb 04 16:36:43 allibis-pc sudo[4820]:  allibis : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/allibis ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start nordvpnd
Feb 04 16:36:44 allibis-pc sudo[4824]:  allibis : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/allibis ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl enable nordvpnd
Feb 04 16:36:50 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:36:50 quic transport needs reconnect, err: Application error 0x100
Feb 04 16:36:50 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:36:50 [Error] retrieving credentials: Unauthorized: Unauthorized
Feb 04 16:38:02 allibis-pc sudo[4930]:  allibis : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/allibis ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/nordvpnd
Feb 04 16:38:32 allibis-pc nordvpnd[1538]: 2023/02/04 16:38:32 [Error] retrieving credentials: Unauthorized: Unauthorized
```

One thing i noticed looking around the other threads, is that they mention `/var/lib/nordvpn/data/.config.ovpn`, however it's nowhere to be seen in my system.

Comment: Contact NordVPN not a Ubuntu issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: after a few interactions with the customer support, they suggested me to use this method to connect to the account via terminal:

1. Run the `nordvpn login` command on your Linux device.
2. Open the provided link in any browser.
3. Complete the login procedure.
4. Right-click on the "Continue" button and select "Copy link address".
5. Run `nordvpn login --callback "URL"` with the previously copied URL in the terminal. Please note that the URL must be surrounded by quotation marks "".
6. Verify that login was successful with nordvpn account.

With this method I was able to log in successfully.

Comment: they usually tell me to  purge nordvpn, rm the config files, download the deb file , update, upgrade, .. it might be a Ubuntu problem for all we know. my nord has been 99% stable since I stopped using USB ethernet adapters and HP X360 Laptops. also re DNS you can now do 'nordvpn set dns 103.86.96.100 103.86.99.100' at terminal. and 'resolvectl status' to check.

Comment: sudo rm /var/lib/nordvpn/data/settings.dat
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/nordvpn